# How to remove Microsoft Async Targeting Pack after upgrading .NET 4.5

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, .net-4.0, .net-4.5

I've installed **Async Targeting Pack** to be able to use its benefits with .NET 4.0 and now I upgraded the project to .NET 4.5 and I don't need it anymore.

**Case 1:**
If I keep it the project gets about 7-8 warnings saying "*The predefined type System.Runtime.CompilerServices.xxx* is defined in multiple assemblies in the global alias..."

**Case 2:**
If I remove the *Microsoft.CompilerServices.AsyncTargetingPack.1.0.0* folder from [Project]\Packages path I get more than a hundred warnings all about the contents of *Microsoft.Commons.targets* which is located at Windows\Microsoft.NET\4.0.xxx

How can I get rid of it without getting any warning?

Answer (score 0):

So I've deleted it via NuGet for the unit test project too in the same solution and it solved it. The unit testing project was the one making the problem.